# Name of an inference rule that I can't find anywhere

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

As a homework question, I must prove, using inference rules, that:

p ∨ q

(¬p ∧ q) → r

---

∴ ¬r → p

I have done the following progress:

1. p ∨ q
2. (¬p ∧ q) → r
3. ¬r → ¬(¬p ∧ q)
4. ¬r → (¬(¬p) ∨ ¬q)
5. ¬r → (p ∨ ¬q)

1 premisse

2 premisse

3 contrapositive from 2

4 morgan law from 3

5 double negation from 4

And I can't figure out how to finish it. I can easily prove the whole expression using a truth-table, but I simply can't find a formal way of merging 1 and 5. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this directly:

$p \to p,$ LEM as an implication

$\neg q \to p,$ $1$ as an implication

$(p \vee \neg q) \to (p \vee p),$ constructive syllogism

$(p \vee \neg q) \to p$

$\neg r \to p,$ hypothetical syllogism from the above and $5$

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have the answer you need, and you can't use this proof anyway since it uses an assumption, but it's kind of cute and I feel like it might be nice to provide a complete non-constructive proof. Feel free to ignore this if you'd like, I'm just throwing this in for fun.

Again continuing where you left off, assume $\neg r.$ By Modus Ponens, we have $p \vee \neg q.$

By conjunction with $(1)$, we now have $(p \vee \neg q) \wedge (p \vee q),$ which we can expand to $(p \vee \neg q \wedge p) \vee (p \vee q \wedge \neg q),$ and then $(p \wedge  p) \vee (q \wedge p) \vee (p \wedge \neg q) \vee (q \wedge \neg q)$ by the distributive property. $p \wedge p$ simplifies to $p$ and $q \wedge \neg q$ simplifies to false, so we get $p \vee (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge \neg q).$

Now using the distributive property in reverse gives us $p \vee (p \wedge (q \vee \neg q)),$ which simplifies to $p \vee p$ and then just $p.$

We assumed $\neg r$ and we reached $p,$ so we can conclude that $\neg r \to p.$

Both the direct proof and the proof by contradiction where we assume $\neg r$ and $p$ are admittedly simpler than this, but like I said I just felt like sharing it for fun.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

You want to prove that $\lnot r \to p$.
you proved that $ \lnot r \to (p\vee \lnot q)$.

Assume  $ \lnot p$.

then by DS, $ \lnot q$.

but the first premise is $ p\vee q$

so, we can't have $ \lnot p \wedge \lnot q$. this is the contradiction.

Comment: All one can conclude is, therefore, due to the contradiction, p.  You haven't proven $\lnot \lnot q \equiv q$.  So we're back $\lnot r \to (p \lor \lnot q).$

Comment: You also can't get $\neg q$ from just assuming $\neg p.$ What you want (and perhaps what you meant) is to assume $\neg p$ and $\neg r.$ Then, from the contradiction you could conclude $\neg(\neg p \wedge \neg r) \leftrightarrow p \vee r \leftrightarrow \neg r \to p.$

Comment: @amWhy The conclusion of his argument is $\lnot r -> p$

Comment: @StephenDonovan I said by DS, disjunctive syllogism.

Comment: I completely understand your logic (pun not intended), but my proof can't involve anything besides inference rules, so assuming ¬p and forcing the contradiction "isn't allowed". But thanks for the help!

Comment: But that's not the argument you made in your post.  You need to assume both $\lnot r \land \lnot p$.  You only assumed $\lnot p$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes, but you don't have $p \vee \neg q,$ only $\neg r \to p \vee \neg q.$ So you need to assume $\neg r$ as well.

Comment: @amWhy $\lnot r $ is the first thing to assume : the antecedent.

Comment: Two of us here corrected you on the same move.  The only way you can get $p\lor q$ is by assuming $\lnot r$, and with modus ponens, you then get $p\lor \lnot q$.  Now you assume, $\lnot p$.... two of us have echoed each other here, and yet you challenge only me.  This proof or yours is not complete. You failed to assume $\lnot r$.

Comment: @amWhy No, without downvoting, i used what the OP already found.